# TWRP: What should I select in Backup on OnePlus 5

Tags: backup, twrp, oneplus-5

I'm new to TWRP and I'm going to be installing a custom.ROM/Kernel. I've messed up my device a few times by installing random things. I've fixed it now, and I'd like to start making backups. I know that the OnePlus 5 has dm-verity and I've heard that dm-verity prevents some backups. What should I select in backup in TWRP for the OP5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that backing up what it selects by default (System, Data, and Boot) are often what you need. System is the entire OS besides the Kernel and Ramdisk. Data is the userdata. Boot is the boot, as the name suggests.